# MongoTemplate equivalent of match all Criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

In Mongosh I can pass an empty object `{}` to match all documents. I cannot find an equivalent in Java MongoTemplate API. The closest is:

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").exists(true));
List<Hierarchy> hierarchies = mongoTemplate.find(query, Hierarchy.class);
```

which translates as

```
{ "_id" : { "$exists" : true}}
```

Is there some better way?

Comment: Have you tried `mongoTemplate.findAll(Hierarchy.class)`?

Comment: Thanks but this would apply only for a searching documents use case. But I need to pass Query to update, remove and other methods. So I am seeking for {} query.

Comment: have you tried `new BasicQuery("{}")` instead of the `Query` interface? That allows you to specify the exact query, which should give you what you want/need?

Comment: Cool, I did not know this subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to retrieve all documents from a collection using the MongoTemplate API in Java:

```
List<Hierarchy> hierarchies = mongoTemplate.find(new Query(),Hierarchy.class);
```